# How to return An arraylist in Rest Webservice

Tags: java, rest

```
//Main service 

@Path("/test")
public class ReturnMultiple {

    public static ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    @POST
    @Path("/new/{name}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public ArrayList<String> display(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        al.clear();
        Todo td = new Todo();
        td.setName(name);
        al.add(td.getName());
        return al;
    }
}

// This is Pojo

public class Todo {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Whenever I hit the service I get this error as Below

> A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java
>   type java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type
>   text/plain was not found

Comment: This static arraylist is not a good idea, what happen if two requests for `/test/new/name` arrive at the same time?

Comment: Regarding the error message, the framework used don't know how to make **text** from an `ArrayList`, that's the issue

Comment: What to write in @produces ?

Comment: MediaType.XML or MediaType.JSON (something like that)

Comment: when i use Application_Json in @produces it give me this error 
A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>, and MIME media type application/json was not found

Comment: Same with Meditype.APPLICATION_XML

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ArrayList and produce TEXT_PLAIN. You'd have to use JSON. To setup JSON message body write in jax-rs you need to supply a @Provider for an ObjectMapper. [Here's an example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.4.1/examples/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/jackson/MyObjectMapperProvider.java):

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need a mapper implementation which helps in the serialization and deserialization. Without that it doesn't know how to convert an arraylist into text/plain or application/json or for that matter any other MIME type.

if you are dealing with application/json, [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library works as really good mapper. It has messagebodyreader and messagebodywriter for you to do the difficult job.

you might have a way to provide a mapper for your rest services (as a provider), in some implementation it picks itself if you use jackson jar which I remember while using resteasy.

Comment: I am new to this , may you please write a code for mapper ? 
Thanks

Comment: In most cases when you include the jackson jar is automatically get registered https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/ as the link says so code won't be required probably, otheriwse here is an example of it with jersey http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Comment: I have included those jars and wrote like below :

@POST
 @Path("/new/{name}")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public ArrayList<String> display(@PathParam("name") String name) {
  al.clear();
  Todo td = new Todo();
  td.setName(name);
  al.add(td.getName());
  return al;
 }

Comment: still you face the same issue? I am not sure what are you using jor jax-rs? is it jersey, resteasy, cxf, restlet, can you list down your jar in the question?

Comment: jax-rs , i used Gson , and i am able to get the output , but now i want to know how can i put this arraylist and two boolean values  in a hashmap
and return the hashmap